# Having trouble with adding lines to a rich text box from a list

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("texter.txt");
        outputFile.WriteLine(txtInput.Text);
        outputFile.Close();

        List<String> mainList = new List<String>();

        StreamReader inputFile;
        inputFile = File.OpenText("texter.txt");
        while (inputFile.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            mainList.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
        }
        inputFile.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < mainList.Count; i++)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = mainList[i];
        }
    }
```

This is inside a button handler, and there is also a text box for input involved.  Whenever I hit the button, however, it overwrites the previous entry.  I want to get everything from my list into the text box.

Comment: Interesting that while there were several suggestions on how to fix the issue, no one bothered to point out the root cause - `=` is an assignment operator, when in reality OP wanted to concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `=` operator which doesn't add anything, it assigns value to a property.
Use `+=` operator or assign the text value to a sum of a previous value + new value.

```
txtOutput.Text += mainList[i];
// or 
txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text +  mainList[i];
// or 
txtOutput.Text = mainList[i] + txtOutput.Text;
```

But I suggest to use `String.Format` instead of `+` or `+=` operator

```
txtOutput.Text = string.Format("{0}\n{1}", mainList[i], txtOutput.Text);
```

Also, you can avoid for-loop using `Aggregate` or `Join` instead.

```
var text = mainList.Aggregate((x, next) => string.Format("{0}\n{1}", next, x));
var text = string.Join("\n", mainList);
```

Also, you can read entire file in one go string using the [ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("texter.txt");
```

Then add it to the TextBox

```
 txtOutput.Text = string.Format("{0}\n{1}", mainList[i], text);
```

Answer (score 0):

3 options :

Fix assignment

```
txtOutput.Text += mainList[i] + Environment.NewLine;
```

Or replace for loop

```
txtOutput.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, mainList);
```

Or replace loop and StreamReader

```
txtOutput.Text = File.ReadAllText("texter.txt");
```